# How to save image files in fragment while changing fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello I have 2 fragments, fragment A and B. In fragment A, I have image uploaded via startActivity and onResultActivity from the external device. I have saved image name and its url as private variables in fragment A. Now I replace fragment A with B to fetch some data, but after coming back to fragment A with data I can no longer see my previously uploaded image. Both the private variables are also reset. Please help me to save the private variables of image during such fragment transactions.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to save data in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onDestroyView`

then retore data in lifecycle you want to use

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class StatedFragment extends Fragment {

    Bundle savedState;

    public StatedFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore State Here
        if (!restoreStateFromArguments()) {
            // First Time, Initialize something here
            onFirstTimeLaunched();
        }
    }

    protected void onFirstTimeLaunched() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save State Here
        saveStateToArguments();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        // Save State Here
        saveStateToArguments();
    }

    private void saveStateToArguments() {
        if (getView() != null)
            savedState = saveState();
        if (savedState != null) {
            Bundle b = getArguments();
            b.putBundle(internalSavedViewState8954201239547, savedState);
        }
    }

    private boolean restoreStateFromArguments() {
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        savedState = b.getBundle(internalSavedViewState8954201239547);
        if (savedState != null) {
            restoreState();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////
    // Restore Instance State Here
    /////////////////////////////////

    private void restoreState() {
        if (savedState != null) {
            // For Example
            //tv1.setText(savedState.getString(text));
            onRestoreState(savedState);
        }
    }

    protected void onRestoreState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    //////////////////////////////
    // Save Instance State Here
    //////////////////////////////

    private Bundle saveState() {
        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        // For Example
        //state.putString(text, tv1.getText().toString());
        onSaveState(state);
        return state;
    }

    protected void onSaveState(Bundle outState) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Would have been helpful if you can demonstrate above with some examples. I am new to fragments, so sorry about that!